Splitting an infinite sum in two parts results in a different result
I am completely puzzled why splitting an infinite sum into two parts, one where the index $i$ is negative, and another where the index $i$ is not negative, leads to a different result.
I posted the code below, and unless I am missing something very basic, which I can't tell, this is a bug. Note that $i$ varies from $-3$ to $\infty$. It's then split into a sum where $i$ goes from $-3$ to $-1$, and another one where $i$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$. Mathematica gives a different result.
Note the only difference between the three parts (x1, x2 and x3) is the range of $i$. Loosely speaking, since we're talking about relative integers, we should have $[k-1, \infty]=[k-1, -1] \cup [0, \infty]$ (because $k$ is a negative integer, which is why that should hold).
j = 1; k = -2; x1 = Simplify[{x1 = 
Sum[((-z)^(i - k + 1)/(i - k + 1)!)*Binomial[j + i, i], 
        {i, k - 1, Infinity}], x2 = Sum[((-z)^(i - k + 1)/(i - k + 1)!)*Binomial[j + i, i], 
        {i, 0, Infinity}], x3 = Sum[((-z)^(i - k + 1)/(i - k + 1)!)*Binomial[j + i, i], 
        {i, k - 1, -1}], x1 - (x2 + x3)}]

The output (difference should be zero):
{-3 + E^-z + 2 z - z^2/2, -E^-z (2 + E^z (-2 + z) + z), -2 + z, -3 + 2 z - z^2/2 + E^-z (3 + z)} 

I really appreciate the help.
Per my calculations, it's x1 that seems to be wrong.

What else can be said than that it is a bug in Mathematica?

... and yes, x1 is wrong, x2+x3 is correct.

ORIGINAL answer:
The problem is with Binomial[n, m] where n<0. Thus, a fix is to
replace it with a modified binomial such as B[n_, m_] := If[n<0, 0, Binomial[n, m]]. The recent version $14.1$ of Mathematica has
PascalBinomial[] for this reason. However, it does not currently
work for symbolic summation in this case. This is a correct code:
ClearAll[B, f, z, j, k];
B[n_, m_] := If[n<0, 0, Binomial[n, m]];
f[i_] := ((-z)^(i - k + 1)/(i - k + 1)!)*B[j + i, i];
j = 1; k = -2;
{x1 = Sum[ f[i], {i, k-1, Infinity}],
x2 = Sum[ f[i], {i, 0, Infinity}],
x3 = Sum[ f[i], {i, k-1, -1}],
x1 - (x2 + x3)} //Simplify //InputForm
(* {-((2 + E^z*(-2 + z) + z)/E^z), -((2 + E^z*(-2 + z) + z)/E^z), 0, 0} *)

However notice the difference between finite versus infinite summation:
ClearAll[B, f, z, j, k];
B[n_, m_] := Binomial[n, m];
f[i_] := ((-z)^(i - k + 1)/(i - k + 1)!)*B[j + i, i];
j = 1; k = -2; Inf = 100;
{x1 = Sum[ f[i], {i, k-1, Inf}],
x2 = Sum[ f[i], {i, 0, Inf}],
x3 = Sum[ f[i], {i, k-1, -1}]};
Print[x1 - (x2+x3) //Simplify //InputForm]
(* 0 *)
Inf = Infinity;
{x1 = Sum[ f[i], {i, k-1, Inf}],
x2 = Sum[ f[i], {i, 0, Inf}],
x3 = Sum[ f[i], {i, k-1, -1}]};
Print[x1 - (x2+x3) //Simplify //InputForm]
(* -3 + 2*z - z^2/2 + (3 + z)/E^z *)

The bug is due to nonzero values of Binomial[n, m] for n<0 and infinite summation.

NEW answer:
As 'azerbajdzan' commented, the bug is elsewhere. I tracked it down to:
ClearAll[f, z, j, k, s];
j = 1; k = -2;
f[i_] := ((-z)^(i - k + 1)/(i - k + 1)!)*Binomial[j + i, i];
s[m_] := Sum[ f[i], {i, m, Infinity}];
Do[Print["m=", m, " ", s[m] //InputForm], {m, -3, -1}];
s1 = s[-3]; s2 = f[-3] + f[-2] + s[-1];
Print[{s1, s2, s1-s2} //Simplify //InputForm]
(* m=-3 -1/2*(-2 + 6*E^z - 4*E^z*z + E^z*z^2)/E^z *)
(* m=-2 Sum[((1 + i)*(-z)^(3 + i))/(3 + i)!, {i, -2, Infinity}] *)
(* m=-1 -((2 - 2*E^z + z + E^z*z)/E^z) *)
(* {-3 + E^(-z) + 2*z - z^2/2, -((2 + z)/E^z), -3 + 2*z - z^2/2 + (3 + z)/E^z} *)

Note that s1 and s2 should have been equal to each other but are not.
This is a bug. Also note that the s[-2] infinite sum is not summed, but
that s[-3] is, although incorrectly.

OP did not say he wants Binomial[n, m]=0 for n<0. He is fine with definition that Mathematica uses for negative arguments. So your argument that binomial should be zero is irrelevant. The bug is elsewhere.

@azerbajdzan Thanks for that comment! I will have to fix my answer now.

@azerbajdzan Exactly, thank you for sparing me the trouble. I want the binomial as generic as possible, fully generic.

Using AsymptoticSumyou get expected result
j = 1; k = -2;  {
asy1 = AsymptoticSum[((-z)^(i - k + 1)/(i - k + 1)!)*Binomial[j + i, i], {i, k - 1, inf}, inf -> Infinity], 
asy2 = AsymptoticSum[((-z)^(i - k + 1)/(i - k + 1)!)*Binomial[j + i, i], {i, 0, inf}, inf -> Infinity], 
x3 = Sum[((-z)^(i - k + 1)/(i - k + 1)!)*Binomial[j + i, i], {i,k - 1, -1}] ,asy1-(asy2+x3)}
(*{-2 E^-z - E^-z z, 2 - 2 E^-z - z - E^-z z, -2 + z, 0}*)

As @azerbajdzan mentions the first sum x1  is incorrect(don't know why).
